# scanf printing to console?

Tags: c

I am writing a program to test multiple DFAs and NFAs. Here is my code:

```
char input[256];
DFA dfa = oneA();
while(1){
    printf("\nEnter an input: ");
    scanf("%s", input);
    if (strcmp(input, "quit") == 0){
        break;
    }
    printf("\nResults for input \"%s\": ", input);
    printf("%s", DFA_execute(dfa, input) ? "true" : "false");
}
```

Here is the behavior I would expect:

```
Testing DFA that recognizes exactly "zxy"
Enter an input: *zxy*
Results for input "zxy": true
```

where the stars just indicate which part is user input.
However, what ends up happening is this:

```
Testing DFA that recognizes exactly "zxy"
Enter an input: *zxy*
zxy

Results for input "zxy": true
```

Something between my two print statements is printing the input and a newline character to the console. Strangely enough, it seems to be scanf, as multiple calls to scanf will replicate this behavior. Just the below code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char input[256];
    scanf("%s", input);
    printf("%s", input);
}
```

Produces this output:

```
*test*
test
test
```

I'm not sure why as I don't think scanf is supposed to output anything. Can anyone help me clarify what is going on?

Comment: You're hitting `<enter>` on your keyboard after typing `zxy`. That advances the console cursor position to the next line. Your subsequent print starts with `printf("\n...`, which introduces the second line advance. In short, this is doing *exactly* what you told it to do.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm still confused though, why is it printing zxy again? Also, how do I enter input without going to the next line on the console?

Comment: Would using a reference resolve it?  &input instead of input as the second param. to scanf?

Comment: @AdrianM. using &input gives me the same result (as far as I know char array is already a reference type)

Comment: That is true, it is a reference.  It's not being reproduces using an online compiler...The input is printed on the input line, but not a second time.

Comment: I find it difficult to believe the former claim. The latter claim is not possible without using platform-dependent IO operations (like kbhit, et'al). The only way`zxy` is dumped to console twice as-shown  in the posted code that *supposedly* does so is if `strcmp` is macro-substituted to both dump the src string *and* compare the results. And I find that incredibly hard to believe. Can you produce what you'r seeing stand-alone (i.e. without any the DFA calls in an actual [mcve] )?.

Comment: @WhozCraig I edited the post with a more minimal example. The same behavior is persisting. Could this have something to do with the IDE I am using? (CLion)

Comment: Simply looks like the text window is not mixing input and output on the same line - and its echoing input.  C does not specify that behavior detail, so both look  OK to me

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what is causing this but it does seem to be IDE-specific (I am using CLion). Compiling from the command line with gcc does not reproduce the problem.